# Import csv from executed file raises error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a working python3 program that imports various standard library modules, e.g.

```
import re
import os
import csv
...
```

It runs without problem when I execute it directly. Now I want to run it through an `exec` call from an outside script, like this:

```
with open("main.py") as main:
    exec(main.read())
```

But I get an error:

```
ImportError: no module named 'csv'
```

How can I make the executed script import all modules correctly?

I thought that all these three modules belong to the python standard library so, why the first two modules seem to be found while the third is not?

Comment: I just tried replicating it with python 2.7 and 3.4 on ubuntu without issue. Do you by any chance have a file or directory named csv in your working directory?

Comment: @CasualDemon No file named csv. I have just tried on ubuntu and it works, as you say. It is on windows that it won't work. Windows is my target platform and I'm testing it there. Since I am using py2exe I will check if the error can be related to that. I'll update soon. Thank you for your comment.